# What really happens when a mobile app gets updated to a recent version by it's developers, shouldn't everyone get the same update at the same time?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, whatsapp

This sparked a little argument in my office. I noticed that some of my colleagues see WhatsApps recently introduced **"end-to-end encryption"** message in their chats while some don't. Why is it that others can see that message and others can't? Is it because my whatapp version is more recent than theirs? What really happens when a mobile app gets updated to a recent version by it's developers, shouldn't everyone anywhere regardless of android get the same update at the same time? Or is this somewhat related to the android version which in turn is managed by and dependent on the hardware manufacturer?